# Connect to a USB device in Windows via another computer (Raspberry Pi) on the same network?

Tags: linux, windows, networking, usb

I have a Windows computer and a Linux Raspberry Pi which are about 25 feet away from each other, but they're both connected via ethernet to the same network. I have a USB device (FPGA board) that I want to use with my Windows computer, *but* it's located near the Raspberry Pi.

I cannot change the location of anything in this whole scenario. So now one way to connect the USB device to the Windows computer is by using a long 25 feet USB cable. But a better way might be if I can plug the USB device input my Raspberry Pi, which then sends all data to the Windows computer over the network.

he Raspberry Pi does not need to use that data itself. In other words, the Raspberry Pi will be acting as a 'surrogate' USB port for the Windows computer. Is this possible somehow ?

Comment: I used to use [this Windows client](https://www.virtualhere.com/usb_client_software) with [this Linux server](https://virtualhere.com/usb_server_software). It was few years ago. I recall back then the trial version allowed me to use one USB device. Investigate for your own what the current policy is.

Comment: It's an FPGA board which I program. It's like another raspberry pi-like device but more low level and more customizable. I work on it at a specific location in my house which I cannot move easily :/

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, yeah seems like this is exactly what I want! Haven't tried it yet though. If only there's a free / open source version of the same concept.

Comment: By using usb/ip, maybe. Not sure how well the Windows client(s) work though.